# activerecord json output not showing relationship in output

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a posts model and of course authors which is a foreign key relationship to my users.

I am trying to output in JSON, the posts with the authors names. 
I know this is rails 101, but I can't call `post.author` because I'm not in a view.

I've tried doing this a few ways, but none seem to be working.

My post model has

```
 belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => :author_id

def post_author
 self.each {|a| a['author'] = User.find(a.id)}
end
```

in my controller I've tried all sorts of

```
posts=Post.find(:all).includes(:user)

#or
posts=Post.find(:all).includes(:post_author) #don't think this is right anyway, but tried 

#and 
posts = Post.find(:all)
posts = JSON::Parse(posts.to_json()).merge('author'=>posts.author) #or posts.user, etc etc
```

of course, none of these have worked, which is why I'm posting here. What's the best way to get the author of a post.

----------------------update ---------------------------

@rjz provided a response which works, but I'm hoping isn't the best way. 
He suggested using

```
posts.to_json(:include=> :user,:only[:username])
```

this meant I was only getting the username back, but I need more than that so I started using `:except` instead. The problem here is that I've got a fields like `id` which I need in the post, but not in the author, but if I exclude them in this manner, the field is excluded from the results completely. I'm also having to list out each field I need, and I'm not sure if that is the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to tease the name of your association a bit to get exactly what you want, but what you're looking for is the `:include` option when you serialize with [`to_json`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json):

```
posts.to_json(:include => :user)
```

Comment: that gets me the user @rjz, but brings up the new problem of now returning everything, including email, etc. I tried `posts.to_json(:include => :user, :select => :username)`, but that didn't work. can I mix a select in with this?

Comment: Not exactly, but you can use the `:only` option in `to_json` to limit what fields get serialized. It's detailed in the documentation I linked above.

Comment: Thanks rjz, this is an ok, solution. I'm using `:except` for now, but I'm having to either remove or add all the fields for both tables. I'm hoping there may be a better way, and I'll update the question. If there isn't a better response, the answer is yours. thanks again